# ToolTip while Drop Down ComboBox

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a combo box in my project which takes a certain amount of numbers from a file.
This Combo drops down the list of the numbers each of represents something.
That something I want to be displayed in a tooltip when the mouse hovers on the combo box.
Until now everything has gone fine.
What I want now is to see the tooltip when the mouse rolls over the list of the dop down combo.
How can I do that? Until now the internet didn't give me something to work on it.
Is there some one to assist me on that?

Comment: Good luck: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e234c4a7-0cf7-4284-a072-8152f7593002/

Comment: Dear Hans, thanks for your answer. But I can't figured out from the solution which you give it to me. First because I'm not familiar with c# and second as the answered says don't cover the solution i want, because my need is to see the ToolTip in every item of the DropDown List before the selection. So i'm in the same position as before. Please anybody assist me

Comment: Hmya, if it wasn't clear from the linked answer, this is something that's *hard* to do.  It is not impossible, the link shows you how to get started.  If you don't know how to finish it, consider putting a bounty on your question to find somebody else do your work.  Or you can contract it out, it will cost a grand or two.  Wait until you've got at least a couple of hundred rep, this isn't fun code.

Comment: Yes Hans it very hard code, i want to thank you very much for your efforts until now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're looking for, where a tooltip appears over a ComboBox item you mouse over?

[image]

If so take a look at this article on codeproject.com:
[A Windows.Forms.ComboBox with Item ToolTips for 32 bit Windows XP (SP2)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/32XPComboBoxToolTip.aspx)

It's VB.NET and currently displays a ComboBox item's text when moused over; I'm sure you can adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: Well Dear Jay thank you for your answer, and i have to admit that your idea in this condition was the most closer. But i thing (after all the work i give to this) that we need a new EVENT for the ComboBox named "POINTING THE LIST ITEMS" in order to have some event arguments, from there, to handle. Finally i agree with Hans, it is much dificult code. Or my be a Combo Box which already have catch these enets!!

Answer (score 0):

'--------------------------------------------------------------
' make sure the property of your combobox has DrawMode set
' to OwnerDrawFixed, this will allow the event to be triggered
'--------------------------------------------------------------
Dim ComboBox1ShowToolTips As Boolean = False
Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DrawItem

```
    e.DrawBackground()

    Dim G As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim Brush As Brush

    Brush = New SolidBrush(e.BackColor)

    G.FillRectangle(Brush, e.Bounds)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ComboBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString, e.Font,
             New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)

    e.DrawFocusRectangle()

    If ComboBox1ShowToolTips And e.Index = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex Then
        Dim p As Point = New Point(ComboBox1.Location.X + 50, ComboBox1.Location.Y + ComboBox1.Height + (10 + e.Index * 10))

        Select Case ComboBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString
            Case "item1"
                ToolTip2.Show("item1 tooltip", ComboBox1, p)
            Case "item2"
                ToolTip2.Show("item2 tooltip", ComboBox1, p)
            Case "item3"
                ToolTip2.Show("item3 tooltip", ComboBox1, p)
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDown
    ComboBox1ShowToolTips = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.DropDownClosed
    ComboBox1ShowToolTips = False
    ToolTip2.Hide(ComboBox1)
End Sub
```